# Farcry 4 - How do I use hand signals (Salute, etc)

Tags: far-cry-4

I am trying to search on how to chat using the **hand signals** such as saluting; but I keep finding results on text chat and how it doesn't exist or voice chat.

It tells me to use the `[?]` key. What the hell is the `[?]` key?!?!?! I hit the question mark, but nothing happens, even with Shift. What should I do?

Comment: [?] Might imply that you still need to bind the key. Have you checked your key binding settings?

Comment: I checked Controls, but it doesn't show communicate or such anywhere. Can you tell me where I can find the binding for it?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Coop menu button. It is bound to 'V' by default. The binding can be changed by going to 'Keyboard and Mouse' (or Controller I suppose), then 'Customize controls' in the options.

[image]

Once you are in a co-op game it is used to bring up the coop action menu, as seen here.

[image]